Why Ajax post method is not connecting to the php page "view.php" and always the error part of the response is the output
I have id taken from an html element and i want to use it in my php page, so i cross it to php page using post method but it seems to be not working in my case. And everytime the error part of the response is executing and not succeeding.

// product fetching from database 

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.brand').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var brandId = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(brandId);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'view.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'brandId': brandId},
            
            success: function(response){
                $('.janvi').html(response);
            },
            error: function(){
                $('.janvi').html('Error fetching products.');
            }
        });
        
    });
});


<?php
// Database connection settings
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "customer";

echo("hi");


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
echo("hi");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Retrieve brand ID from AJAX POST request
$brandId = $_POST['brandId'];
echo("hi");
// Fetch products based on brand ID from the database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM productdetail WHERE name = '$brandId'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // Output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<p>" . $row["name"] . "</p>";



    }
} else {
    echo "No products found for this brand.";
}

// Close connection
$conn->close();
?>


I tried to get the data brandId to php page for further usage using post method but it seems not be working .

You are vulnerable to the sql injection attack. Open developer tools in your browser and inspect the networking tab after you click to see actual response. My guess is that the database connection fail and you end up dying.

"And everytime the error part of the response is executing" - please clarify; are you saying that the error handler of the AJAX request gets triggered, or are you saying that the success handler is inserting one of the error messages you output in the PHP part, into the page? (And if the latter, which one?)
